# cmake builds dynamic header files every time

Tags: c, build, cmake

I have a cmake project wherein I build .c & .h files from .lcm files (see e.g., Lightweight Communications Marshalling (please google for this, my reputation points only allow 2 links :)). The folder structure is as follows -

- root

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - lcmtypes

    - example_msg.lcm
  - src/test_lib

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - test_lib.c, test_lib.h
  - src/listener.c
  - src/send_message.c

Some notes:

1. example_msg.lcm generates example_msg.h / example_msg.c which are compiled as a static library, say libexample_msg.a They are also copied to a new folder build/include/lcmtypes.
2. listener.c & send_message.c compile as stand-alone executables using libexample_msg.a
3. test_lib compiles as a static library libtest_lib.a, independent of libexample_msg.a and copies test_lib.h to build/include/test_lib.

However,

1. if I change something in test_lib.h, cmake recompiles libexample_msg.a all over again;
2. on the other hand, if I change something in listener.c, cmake does not compile libexample_msg.a (which is expected, since nothing in example_msg.lcm changed);
3. if I do not install test_lib.h header, and change something in test_lib.h, libexample_msg.a does not recompile.

Is this behavior expected? I don't think it is. Is there something I am missing in the cmake process? How do I prevent libexample_msg.a from being compiled if test_lib changes?

root.CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.0)
lcmtypes_build()

add_executable(send_message src/send_message.c)
pods_use_pkg_config_packages(send_message lcm lcmtypes_p1)

add_executable(listener src/listener.c)
pods_use_pkg_config_packages(listener lcm lcmtypes_p1)
pods_install_executables(send_message listener)
add_subdirectory(src/test_lib)
```

test_lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(test_lib test_lib.c)
pods_use_pkg_config_packages(test_lib lcm lcmtypes_p1)

pods_install_libraries(test_lib)
pods_install_headers(test_lib.h
     DESTINATION test_lib)
```

lcmtypes_build() creates the .c/.h files from .lcm files and builds the lcmtypes_p1 library. Note that pods_install_* are just macroc to install() for a libraries, headers, executables. pods_use_pkg_config_packages(target dep1 dep2) executes include_directories(), target_link_libraries() and add_dependencies() after parsing pkg-config's output for dep1 and dep2. See [lcmtypes.cmake](https://code.google.com/p/libbot/source/browse/trunk/bot2-core/cmake/lcmtypes.cmake) for lcmtypes_build() and [pods.cmake](https://code.google.com/p/libbot/source/browse/trunk/bot2-core/cmake/pods.cmake) for these macros.

### Update

I would draw your attention to lines 169 - 186 of lcmtypes.cmake. 169 adds a custom_target called lcmgen_c which is then added as dependency on libexample_msg.a.

Comment: This is unasnwerable without seeing all the relevant parts of the CMakeLists - how are we supposed to know why something happens when you don't show how you're doing it?

Comment: my bad, i added the CMakeLists.txt above.